# DataGridView rounding

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a specific round function for a calculated column in a datagridview.  When we change the precision, we recalculate the column and round it with our specific formula.

I was curious if there was a better way to accomplish this.  IE not round the number, but tell  how many decimal point to display. but the problem comes in when it needs to be rounded.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think the specific function serves a specific rounding purpose, you need to give examples as what is expected

Answer (score 1):

As such one thing has nothing to do with the other.

If you are rounding to pennies / cents and display in dollars / pounds with no bits

You can on display truncate or round to the pound/dollar
If you view truncate as a somewhat strange rounding operation.
The data is already rounded, and is then rounded again for display.

This is something that you have to be real careful of particularly if you are careless enough to start calculating based on the displayed value...

Avoid displaying to a different precision than you are rounding to at all costs would be my advice.

Comment: thanks Tony.  I was hoping I would not have to recalculate it to get the rounding I wanted.